# Prestashop make the integer explode in smarty

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

I am doing a small module in prestashop. In that I have taken a database 
(ps_customer_module) like this

```
id image_id customer_name 
1  2        john
2  23       simon
3  45       doe
4  9        rocky
```

Now I am fetching the total database like this from module

```
$get_users = 'SELECT * FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'customer_module;
$users = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS( $get_users );
```

here when I am doing print_r($users). I am getting the result like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [image_id] => 2
            [customer_name] => john
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [image_id] => 23
            [customer_name] => simon
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [image_id] => 45
            [customer_name] => doe
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [image_id] => 9
            [customer_name] => rocky
        )              

)
```

Now I have assigned the array to the smart template like this

```
$this->context->smarty->assign( 'users', $users );
```

and I am showing all the result in a list with foreach loop like this

```
<ul>
    {foreach from=$users item=row}
    <li>
        <h3>{$row.customer_name}</h3>
        <img src="img/{$row.image_id}/{$row.image_id}.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```

above the method works fine with the single image_id number image. Lets say about image_id 1 so its working fine there. But if the image id is 45 then its doing like

```
<img src="img/45/45.jpg" alt="">
```

but the actual image directory is like this

```
<img src="img/4/5/45.jpg" alt="">
```

so can someone kindly tell me how to explode the image_id when there will be an image_id with two digits and make separate them by a / (slash).
Hope you get my point. Any help will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use PHP functions `str_split` and `implode` as modifiers (you can of course do the same in PHP if you want). I've created sample script for that.

PHP file:

```
$users = Array
(
    0 => Array
    (
        'image_id' => 2

    ),
    1 => Array
    (
        'image_id' => 45

    ),
    2 => Array
    (
        'image_id' => 101

    ),
    3 => Array
    (
        'image_id' => 2012

    ),

);

$smarty->assign('users',$users);
```

Smarty template:

```
{foreach from=$users item=row}
    img/{$row.image_id|str_split|implode:'/'}/{$row.image_id}.jpg<br />
{/foreach}
```

Output:

```
img/2/2.jpg
img/4/5/45.jpg
img/1/0/1/101.jpg
img/2/0/1/2/2012.jpg
```

PS. You should provide your PHP data in questions not using `var_dump` but using `var_export` so they can be pasted easily without modifications.